# Convert String[] to List<SelectList>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there an easy way, without looping over all the items in an array manually, to convert to a SelectList from an array of strings for a drop down menu?

Comment: A `List<SelectList>` is effectively a 2-D array (list of lists) - how do you propose to convert the 1-D array to that?

Comment: Is this question about ASP.Net MVC  ?

Comment: Everyone's answers just disappeared...

Comment: @DStanley, I think you answered the question, OP is mistaken to get a `List<SelectList>`, I guess OP actually needs a `SelectList`

Comment: @CallumLinington Because the question is asking to convert an array of _items_ to a list of _lists_.  We need more information to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @DStanley I had been looking at this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-dropdown-list-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ it was using a List<SelectList>?

Comment: @Ellery No, it's using a `List<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: @DStanley allright wow got it thank you that makes more sense. Wasn't reading close enough

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm assuming you need either a `SelectList` or a `List<SelectListTiem>`, not a `List<SelectList>`.  `SelectList` has [a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864.aspx) that takes a collection:

```
string[] strings = new [] { .. strings .. };
SelectList sl = new SelectList(strings);
```

or you can project to a `List<SelectListItem>`:

```
string[] strings = new [] { .. strings .. };
var sl = strings.Select(s => new SelectListItem {Value = s})
                .ToList();
```

Note that `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so if you have a model property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` you can create a `SelectList` and assign it to that property rather than projecting to a `List<SelectListItem>`.  It's functionally the same but the code will be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 11):

This is all assuming we're talking about MVC, not Web Forms

Second to D Stanley's answer, another solution:

```
string[] strings = new [] { ... strings ... };
var selectListItems = strings.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x, Selected = x == "item 1" });
```

A list of `SelectListItem` can also be used to populate an MVC drop down list.

With this method, you can also set other properties on a `SelectListItem` such as, display value.

We can't call `Select` on a `IQueryable` using the `SelectListItem` constructor because LINQ will try and convert that to SQL. Which unless there is a provider for it, is impossible, and also not what we want to achieve.

In order to always assure we can enumerate like I have shown above, we need to force EF or other ORMs to get all our data back. We can do this by calling `ToList()` **BEFORE** we enumerate with `Select`:

```
var selectListItems = strings.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x, Selected = x == "item 1" });
```

As @BCdotWEB has pointed out:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

Is the constructor that this list will inevitably get put into. If I can remember correctly, the razor view should look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedString, new SelectList(x.Strings, "Value", "Text"))
```

Where `x.SelectedString` is where you want the chosen value from the drop down to be put. `x.Strings` is that `selectListItems` we created in the `Controller`/`Service`

Comment: You'll want to call `.ToList()` on the end to get a `List` instead of an `IEnumerable`. Never know when lazy evaluation will bite you if you are not planning for it.

Comment: `SelectListItem` does not have a constructor that takes a value.  You'll have to set the `Value` property explicitly.

Comment: In Razor I used @Html.DropDownList("parameterName", Model) where Model is selectListItems from your answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can use the [SelectList Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx), since it accepts an IEnumerable:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about asp.net webForms you can use this code

```
string[] stringArray= new []{"var1",...};
Dictionary<string,string> listItemSource=stringArray.ToDictionary(i => i, i =>i);
yourDropDownList.DataSource=listItemSource;
yourDropDownList.DataValueField = "value";
yourDropDownList.DataTextField = "key";
yourDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, for `System.Web.Mvc`

```
var mySelectList = new SelectList(stringList.Select(x=> new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x,
    Value = x
}), "Value", "Text");
```